# How to set custom collection model as dataType in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I've created model Client with ClientShema and now I'm creating model Company. One of the fields should be of type Client, I've tried to do that, but it seems to crash

here is some code:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
},
username: {
    type: String,
    required: false
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
}
}, { collection: 'User' });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here is my file, where I wanna to use model provided earlier.

```
const client = require('./client');
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   logo: {
       type: String,
       required: false
   },
   companyName: {
       type: String
   },
   clients: {
       type: [client.Client]
   }
},  { collection: 'Company' });

const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow

```
const client = require('./client');// need to include the schema file
var ClientSchema = mongoose.model('Client').schema;// 'Client' is name of Schema
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   logo: {
       type: String,
       required: false
   },
   companyName: {
       type: String
   },
   clients: {
       type: [ClientSchema]
   }
},  { collection: 'Company' });

 const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

Hope this solves your problem.